# Solution of SDE and product rule

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the following SDE: $dX(t)=(A(t) X(t) + a(t)) dt + (B(t)X(t) + b(t))dW(t)$.

The solution is given by $$X(t)= Z(t) \cdot \left(x + \frac{a(t) -B(t)b(t)}{Z(t)}dt+ \frac{b(t)}{Z(t)} dW(t)\right)$$
where $Z(t)$ is the solution of $$d Z(t) = Z(t) A(t) dt + Z(t)B(t) dW(t)$$ and $X(0)=x$.

To prove this, denote the right hand side of the solution by $Y(t)$, such that $X(t)=Z(t)Y(t)$.

Applying Ito's product rule yields:
\begin{align} Z(t)Y(t)&= x+ Z(t)dY(t) + Y(t)dZ(t) + dZ(t)dY(t)\\ &=  x +Z(t)\left[(A(t) Y(t) + a(t)) dt + (B(t)Y(t) + b(t))dW(t)\right] \\ &+ Y(t)[Z(t) A(t) dt + Z(t)B(t) dW(t)] \\ &+ (B(t)Y(t) + b(t))Z(t)B(t) dW(t).
\end{align}

How can I simplify that further to get to the solution?

Comment: Should I substitute $Z(t), Y(t)$ with their solutions?

Comment: You have the right approach. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the SDE $dX=(AX+a)\,dt+(BX+b)\,dW$ where we omit $\cdot(t)$ for convenience.

With the substitution $X=ZY$ where $dY=F\,dt+G\,dW$ for some $F,G$, we have \begin{align}d(ZY)=(AZY+a)\,dt+(BZY+b)\,dW.\end{align} Simultaneously, from Itô's product rule we obtain \begin{align}d(ZY)&=Z\,dY+Y\,dZ+dZ\,dY\\&=Z(F\,dt+G\,dW)+Y(AZ\,dt+BZ\,dW)+BZG\,dt\\&=(ZF+AZY+BZG)\,dt+(ZG+BZY)\,dW\end{align} using the definition that $dZ=AZ\,dt+BZ\,dW$. Equating the two expressions yields $$(ZF+BZG-a)\,dt+(ZG-b)\,dW=0$$ [so that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2486481/471884) $G=b/Z$ and $F=(a-Bb)/Z$. Thus $$X(t)=Z(t)\left(x+\int_0^t\frac{a(s)-B(s)b(s)}{Z(s)}\,ds+\int_0^t\frac{b(s)}{Z(s)}\,dW_s\right).$$

Comment: Why can we use for $G$ and $F$ that each summand in the second last has to be $0$?

Comment: I mean in this equation: $(ZF+BZG-a)\,dt+(ZG-b)\,dW=0$

Comment: Couldn't it be that one summand is positive and the other negative yielding 0 as result?

Comment: @Alif See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2486481/471884

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I do still struggle withe last step. Where do you put in G and F?

Comment: At the start I specified that $dY=F\,dt+G\,dW$. Result follows from integration.

Comment: Sorry. I got it, since $Y(0)=x$ By the way in this setting the initial condition for $Z$ has to be $Z(0)=1$?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate your effort:)